# Composite search condition in mongo using JS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I am new to Node JS and mongo DB. Working on a project to retrieve data from mongo db from js file. I have condition to search multiple column to get the results.

I have used one column find() method which results are correct.

```
var condition = {firstname:"mark"};
jobs.user.find(condition)
```

I have tried multiple column find() method where results are not coming.

```
var condition = [{firstname:"mark"},{gender:"male"}];
jobs.user.find(condition)
```

How to apply multiple conditions in js file? Any help on this.

Comment: Refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-multiple-conditions. It should be `condition = {firstname:"mark", gender:"male"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
jobs.user.find({ $or:[ { firstname:"mark" }, { gender: "male" } ] });
```

If you need to search for records whose both fields are equal to the specified values, then this can be done like this:

```js
jobs.user.find({ firstname:"mark", gender: "male" });
```

[Here you can see the documentation for operator $or.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

[Here you can see the documentation for operator $and.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)

Answer (score 0):

You can use and/or condition for multiple filter 
.Change your condition to

`condition = { $and : [{firstname:"mark"},{gender:"male"}] };` 
or

`condition = { $or : [{firstname:"mark"},{gender:"male"}] };`

depending on your use case.